# How do I receive mail from React Native app using firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I am creating a "Send Feedback" screen on React Native Expo and I need a way for users to send feedback via a submit form and I need to redirect their emails to my email address. Does anyone have a clue or can offer some direction. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it in another way:

First create a collection (feedback) in your Firebase Cloud Firestore. When a user sends the feedback via the submit form, they make an entry in the collection with the data of the feedback.

Then you can create a Firebase Cloud Functions, that executes 1 time everyday and send you an email with the latest new feedbacks. Make sure to check out nodemailer too.

Comment: This is a great approach, so logical. But I will have to get myself familiarised with nodemailer, which is not an issue. Thank you so much :)